# Query Version of date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to include a date picker in a project and found the source code from an example from this link (visible if you click view source code there): https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

I used all of the references but the style of my date picker is not the same as in the example. Below you can see how I use the references (I assume there is something wrong there - but I can't find the issue). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

What my date picker looks like:

[image]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Project Timelines</title>
    <!-- Project References -->
    <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script src="filteredData.js"></script>
    <script src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Blob.js"></script>
    <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
    <!-- External References -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write(decodeURIComponent('%3Cscript src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.4/cldr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.4/cldr/event.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.4/cldr/supplemental.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.4/cldr/unresolved.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize/number.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize/currency.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize/date.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui-ieshiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-datepicker/2.1.23/angular-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#customDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
      } );
    </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: Start with the required resources (and remove all the other ones) to ensure that it works, and then start adding your other resources. Stop when it breaks and fix it.

Comment: I tried that. I also copied all of the source code, placed into a new text document in sublime and I have the same issue there. Can I find different versions of the query libraries in some way? The result of the source codes doesn't look like their example so I thought they used another version

Comment: I created a jsfiddle, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/s5Lzd49u/2/. I only updated the CSS.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean with updating the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your CSS is not loading correctly for the JQuery DatePicker. On line 31 of your snippet you have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

If you change this to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: using just the // at the first of the URL tells the resource to either use HTTP or HTTPS pending what the server is using. This wont fix the issue.

Comment: Indeed it does, assuming you're running on a server at all. However, looking at the previous questions of the asker, it appears they're running a FileMaker application which likely isn't running on either protocol, so specifying it may work for them. Granted, this won't solve the usual query on this issue - but the context behind it may solve it this time. Hopefully the asker will let us know and put us out of our misery :-) I equally hope it isn't something that simple - otherwise this is just a frustrating issue for the asker rather than a fun one!